# SQL query left join and match by time range of 2nd table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, time, date-range

This is somewhat complex query for my novice level. I’ve tried to use Left Join to combine the two tables but I cannot figure out how to use the Where statement so that the drug removal can be matched up an administration that doesn’t occur either at the same time or within 60mins of removal, the query will display null.

the current query will only display data that are match up in both tables...

The two tables are
•   One is drug removal from cabinet (tbl_REM)

```
OrderNumber (Number)
TransactionType (ShortText)
DispenseAmount (ShortText)
TransactionDateTime (Date/Time)
WasteAmount (ShortText)
```

•   One is drug administration by staff (tbl_MAR)

```
OrderNumber (number)
TransactionType (ShortText)
DispenseAmount (ShortText)
TransactionDateTime (Date/Time)
WasteAmount (shortText)
```

My sql codes

```
SELECT Tbl_REM.OrderNumber, Tbl_REM.TransactionType, Tbl_REM.DispenseAmount, Tbl_REM.TransactionDateTime, Tbl_REM.WasteAmount, Tbl_MAR.Dose, Tbl_MAR.units, Tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time], Tbl_MAR.[Mar Action]
FROM Tbl_MAR RIGHT JOIN Tbl_REM ON Tbl_MAR.Order_number = Tbl_REM.OrderNumber
WHERE (((tbl_MAR.[Mar Action]) Like "given*" Or (tbl_MAR.[Mar Action]) Like "new*") AND ((Tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time])>=Tbl_REM.TransactionDateTime) AND ((tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time]-Tbl_REM.TransactionDateTime)<=1/24))
ORDER BY tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time];
```

some key points

- The two tables are linked by order number
- The query need to display all removal from tbl_REM, join it against any
  removal records by matching up order# and MAR Action=Given and
  transaction time that is within 60mins after a dispense from tbl_REM
- Any drug removed that is not administered will have a null in a new column called Not_Administered
- Drug need to be administered in 60 mins after removal (is there a way to prevent the query from pulling duplicate admin txn once it is claimed by the first dispense? for example, if there are two dispense, but only one admin within 60 mins of each dispense and both with same order#)

Comment: I found your nut! (only because I am one) :P  Change `where` to `AND`.  The limits on tbl_mar (in your where clause now) must occur on the join or the right join behavior is that of a INNER join.  Logically the system performs the desired right join.  Then you tell it to exclude all the null records since they don't match the where clause limits.  You need that limit to as part of the join so the right join records are kept.

Answer (score 0):

Notice all we did was make the where clause criteria part of the join and eliminate some of the ugly ()'s access puts in.  Had to keep one set() for the OR

We did this because the where clause limits were eliminating the nulls created by the outer join.

Keep in mind order of execution FROM occurs first then where clause.

The null records are kept in the from due to the outer join; but lost in the where clause since the nulls don't match the limiting values.  By moving it to the join, the limits are applied as part of the join allowing the null values from the outer joins to remain.

```
SELECT Tbl_REM.OrderNumber
     , Tbl_REM.TransactionType
     , Tbl_REM.DispenseAmount
     , Tbl_REM.TransactionDateTime
     , Tbl_REM.WasteAmount, Tbl_MAR.Dose
     , Tbl_MAR.units
     , Tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time]
     , Tbl_MAR.[Mar Action]
FROM Tbl_MAR 
RIGHT JOIN Tbl_REM 
   ON Tbl_MAR.Order_number = Tbl_REM.OrderNumber
  AND (tbl_MAR.[Mar Action] Like "given*" OR tbl_MAR.[Mar Action] Like "new*")
  AND Tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time] >= Tbl_REM.TransactionDateTime
  AND tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time] - Tbl_REM.TransactionDateTime <= 1/24
ORDER BY tbl_MAR.[MAR Taken Time];
```

Comment: XQbert, thank you! that worked! It makes a lot more sense now, but I was completely missing it.. Thanks again!